# How do I generate access report using aggregate functions?

Tags: ms-access

I have 1 table that generated by count function.

```
No of Employee  Employment Status   Department  Status      
3                DIRECT              ACCTG      REGISTERED      
1                COOP                HR         UNREGISTERED        
2                DIRECT              ACCTG      REGISTERED      
1                DIRECT              ACCTG      UNREGISTERED        
5                DIRECT              IT         REGISTERED      
3                COOP                ACCTG      REGISTERED      
2                COOP                MARKETING  UNREGISTERED
```

How do I create a report like this?

```
Department  DIRECT  COOP    REGISTERED  UNREGISTERED    Total
ACCTG         6      3         8           1             9
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` based aggregation can be used

```
SELECT Department,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] ='DIRECT' then [No of Employee] end) as DIRECT,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] ='COOP' then [No of Employee] end) as COOP,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] ='REGISTERED' then [No of Employee] end) as REGISTERED,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] ='UNREGISTERED' then [No of Employee] end) as UNREGISTERED,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] ='REGISTERED' then [No of Employee] end) as REGISTERED,
       SUM( Case when [Employment status] in ( 'DIRECT', 'COOP') then [No of Employee] end) as Total
GROUP BY Department
```